# A version of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Here we use [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). I'm trying to prove below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $p, q \in [1, \infty)$. Let $f,f_n \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ and  $g,g_n \in \mathcal L_q (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $g_n \to g$ a.e. Assume $|f_n|^p \le |g_n|^q$ a.e. for all $n$ and $\|g_n\|_q \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \|g\|_q$. Then $\|f_n -f\|_p \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof** It follows from $|f_n|^p \le |g_n|^q$ a.e. for all $n$ that $|g|^q - |f|^p\ge 0$ a.e. So $\int (|g|^q - |f|^p)$ is well-defined in the extended non-negative real numbers. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int (|g|^q - |f|^p) &= \int \liminf_n (|g_n|^q - |f_n|^p) \\
&\le \liminf_n \int (|g_n|^q - |f_n|^p) \quad \text{by Fatou's lemma}\\
&\overset{(\star)}{=} \int|g|^q - \limsup_n \int |f_n|^p,
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int (|g|^q+|f|^p) &= \int \liminf_n (|g_n|^q+|f_n|^p) \\
&\le \liminf_n \int (|g_n|^q+|f_n|^p) \quad \text{by Fatou's lemma} \\
&\overset{(\star)}{=} \int |g|^q + \liminf_n \int |f_n|^p,
\end{align}
$$
where $(\star)$ follows from below lemma, i.e.,

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511767/if-a-n-is-convergent-then-liminf-a-nb-n-lim-a-n-liminf-b-n) Let $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb R$ for all $n$. If $(a_n)$ is convergent, then $\liminf (a_n+b_n) = \lim a_n + \liminf b_n$.

It follows from $\int|g|^q$ is finite that
$$
\limsup_n \int |f_n|^p \le \int |f|^p \le \liminf_n \int |f_n|^p.
$$

As such, $\lim_n \|f_n\|_p = \|f\|_p$. The claim then follows from below **Lemma**, i.e.,

> [Lemma:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511720/if-f-n-to-f-mu-a-e-and-f-n-1-to-f-then-f-n-f-to-0/4511818#4511818) Let $f_n, f \in \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $\|f_n - f\|_p \to 0$.

Comment: It all seems correct. As long as the latter lemma holds (which I have no doubt about, it's just that I'm not used to Bochner integrals just yet), there are only manipulations of real numbers which are all fine.